# CMake configure for Android fails

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile a dynamic library for Android. I use CMake-gui on Windows to do it. I successfully built the library (TagLib) a few years ago. But now the toolchain doesn't work anymore.

If I try to point the *android.toolchain.cmake* script to NDK R18, it fails with this error message:

```
Android: Targeting API '22' with architecture 'arm', ABI 'armeabi-v7a', and processor 'armv7-a'
CMake Error at C:/app/cmake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-NDK.cmake:97 (message):
  Android: No toolchain for ABI 'armeabi-v7a' found in the NDK:
```

I think it might be related to the fact that Android NDK now switched from GCC to Clang. So I tried an older NDK R16b. Now it gets a little bit further but still fails now with this error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/app/cmake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):   The C compiler

    "c:/app/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Moje/QtProjects/taglib_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_9e009/fast"
    C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_9e009.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9e009.dir/build

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Moje/QtProjects/taglib_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9e009.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

    c:\app\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
-target armv7-none-linux-androideabi --sysroot=C:/app/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-22/arch-arm  -isystem C:\app\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-22\arch-arm\usr\include
-isystem C:\app\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-22\arch-arm\usr\include\arm-linux-androideabi
-g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_9e009.dir\testCCompiler.c.o   -c C:\Moje\QtProjects\taglib_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error: armv7-none-linux-androideabi: No such file or directory

    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-target'

    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-fno-integrated-as'

    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-fno-limit-debug-info'

    CMakeFiles\cmTC_9e009.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_9e009.dir/testCCompiler.c.o' failed

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9e009.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Moje/QtProjects/taglib_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

    Makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_9e009/fast' failed

    mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_9e009/fast] Error 2
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the test command and why it fails. Do you have any idea?

And after all is my approach to build a dynamic Android library correct or are there better ways to do it? I don't use Android Studio, I develop my application in QtCreator.

Comment: Please, format build logs as a **code** (`Ctrl+K` or `{}` button), not as a *blockquote*. The latter formatting doesn't preserve newlines; it is very difficult to read such logs.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was almost the same when I tried to build an Android .apk on my macOS with a console command. Whereas Visual Studio GUI builds ok, the **msbuild** makes an error:

```
error XA5101: C compiler for target Arm was not found.
```

It's discussed on [Xamarin forum here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/448337/xamarinandroid-makebundlenativecodeexternal-failed.html).

The work-around found here and worked for me is to switch off **BundleAssemblies** parameter in **Android.csproj**:

```
<BundleAssemblies>False</BundleAssemblies>
```

Also my solutions with wrong NDK and toolchain paths were founded [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101908/getting-error-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-d-platforms-when-building-on-vsts). I installed the latest versions of Android SDK and NDK.